# Is it considered keyword stuffing to use similar alt text on all images in a thumbnail gallery?

Tags: seo, html, alt-attribute, photo-gallery, keyword-stuffing

I have a thumbnail gallery of 50 photos under the category of "Mustang 1969".
Now for each image I have this `alt` attribute:

```
alt="blue ford mustang 1969"
```

The only part that's changing is the first word "blue" which depends on the car.
Is this considered Keyword Stuffing? Will Google penalize my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine considering it will change the meaning as the first will be different.

Also, at times when you have more images, it becomes hard to have the level of uniqueness.

So, any more changes if you can bring would be good.

Note: Focus more on content quality (Maintain the uniqueness) in general and do not worry too much about it.

Comment: Thanks @TopQnA, what happens in the case of using only 1 alt attribute text for all images on 1 page. As all images are different but under the same category. For example Images of "Moon Eclipse".

Comment: Well, there are many situations where people don't have ALT tag and it works fine. it doesn't have a massive ranking impact. So, don't think too much. Now, to answer your question, images must have its title or description which will differentiate one with another so you can fetch words/phrases which will make it unique. In worse case scenario if you can't make unique then i would say may be leave it black and let Google think about it based on page description but i can't back this with any official recommendation from Google.